# Create buckets of an excel column

Tags: excel

I have column in excel like

```
A
1000
2000
3000
.
.
. 
200000
```

I have to create another field such that it buckets A into say 4 buckets/groups as bucket1, bucket2, bucket3, bucket4. Bucket1 contains smaller values, bucket2 contains higher values, buckets3 contains further higher values and so on.

A             B
    1000         bucket2
    200000       bucket4 
    3000         bucket2
    .            . 
    .            .
    30000        bucket3
    2000         bucket2
    10           bucket1

How do i do this in excel?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And do you need to split the list into four equal groups?

Comment: Yes. Equal groups would do. I tried using nested IF statements but that turned out to be very lengthy.

Comment: Would you like to use VBA or not?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED. Please try in say L1 `0`, M1 `.25`, M2 `.5`, M3 `.75` M4 `1` and in L2:

```
=PERCENTILE(A:A,M1)
```

copied down to L4.

In B1 copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,L$1:M$4,2)
```